# Getting build Errors for Certain Packages

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, package.json

Below are the Exceptions Errors that i am getting while ng build
[Error while Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXMVz.png)

My Package json file is below: -

```
{
  "name": "angular-check",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "launchIdc": "ng serve"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "angular-google-charts": "^0.1.6",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "countries-map": "^4.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "d3": "^5.14.2",
    "d3v4-bullet": "^1.0.7",
    "json-view": "^0.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.8.1",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.5.207",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.8"
  }
}
```

With Angular Version Info below -

```
ng v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 10.2.3
Node: 14.21.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.2.5
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1002.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1002.4
@angular-devkit/core            10.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.2.3
@angular/animations             11.0.0
@angular/cdk                    10.0.0
@angular/cli                    10.2.3
@angular/material               10.0.0
@schematics/angular             10.2.3
@schematics/update              0.1002.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.8
```

When i removed this particular package, then on ng build error came on angular2-text-mask.
I deleted multiple time node_modules and Reinstall it again but the error is still there?
Do anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if You're using Correct Package Versions including Angular.

Also, Delete `node_modules` folder, Do a fresh `npm install` & Try again.